# Window.innerheight minus number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a way in javascript to get the inner window height minus 90px.

I know how to get the inner height from te window by using 'window.innerheight' but i dont know how to get the 90px of it.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: isn't it just window.innerheight-90?

Comment: I don't understand. Why not use `window.innerHeight - 90`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var height = window.innerHeight - 90;
```

Comment: I don't know what i did wrong but i copied your code and now it works :D thnx